Serving web applications using oapi-codegen net/http strict server
I have an API developed with oapi-codegen using net/http and strict-server generation. I'm also using the validation middleware provided ("github.com/oapi-codegen/nethttp-middleware".OapiRequestValidatorWithOptions).
What I'm trying to figure out how to do but failing to do so is how to serve my Flutter Web App in this context.
I tried serving my web app manually by adding a route handler to the underlying http.ServerMux using http.FileServer.
router := http.NewServeMux()
router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../../web/build/web")))

This unfortunately did not work because the validation middleware didn't find that route registered in the OpenAPI I'm using.
I then tried adding the route to the spec, using content: text/html: {}. Due to the strict-server generation though, I do not have access to the underlying http.ResponseWriter and http.Request, and cannot pass them to the http.FileServer handler to just use that. The oapi-codegen generated route expects a response with:
type TexthtmlResponse struct {
    Body io.Reader

    ContentLength int64
}

Do you have any ideas on how to approach this? I'm fairly new to Go and currently feeling a tad overwhelmed.
